# How to download Invoice without login Magento Admin?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, api, invoice

I need to get invoice without login Magento admin, is it possible using any CRM or API Services?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below Magento API.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrderInvoice/sales_order_invoice.info.html

Comment: Gettting error. Source code :https://justpaste.it/6e6ih Output : https://snag.gy/evD1dq.jpg @Kishan Patadia

Comment: Chances are you have some whitespace in your file.

Comment: After remove white spaces : output : https://snag.gy/5tVlRE.jpg  source code: https://justpaste.it/6v711